# Copy list of objects across buckets while keeping object prefixes intact

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, minio, object-storage, minio-client

> ℹ︎ This question is about the *MinIO Client*, not the MinIO Server object storage!

I have two S3-compatible buckets `A` and `B`, and I need to copy a list of objects from `A` to `B`. The catch is that

1. I do not want to copy *all* objects from `A`, nor do my objects all have a shared prefix; instead, I have a list (multi-line text file) of objects that I need to copy. So I cannot just use `mc cp --recursive` or `mc mirror` (as far as I can see).
2. I need to preserve the *entire* object keys on `B`, including the full prefixes.

For example, say I have the following list (in a file `objects.txt`):

```
a/b/1.txt
c/2.txt
d/e/3.txt
f/1.txt
```

And after the copy operation I expect all these objects, with their original names, to reside in `B`.

My initial attempt to achieve this was the following command:

```bash
mc cp $(sed 's,^,s3/A/,' objects.txt) s3/B
```

Unfortunately the resulting bucket `B` had the following listing:

```
B/1.txt
B/2.txt
B/3.txt
```

That is, `mc` treated the object keys as “file paths” and stripped the “directory name”, and it lost one object that had a duplicate key after stripping the prefix.

My current workaround is to use an explicit loop, i.e.

```bash
while read -r object; do
  mc cp s3/A/"$object" s3/B/"$object"
done <objects.txt
```

… But this is *a lot* slower. Part of the issue is that my `mc` is containerised, so every invocation is spawning a new Singularity container. Furthermore, the copy operation does not seem to take advantage of the fact that both buckets are in the same region: I am getting average throughput of 10 MiB/s with a wide variation: it seems that `mc cp` is moving all the data via my local compute node rather than moving it directly between buckets. Ideally a direct copy would be performed (for comparison, `mc mirror` achieves > 1 GiB/s throughput).

Comment: `mc` seems similar to the AWS CLI, so it is unlikely that `mc` is downloading and uploading while performing the copy operation. You could test this by copying a small (eg 1K) and a big (eg 10GB) object and comparing the speeds.

Comment: If you want to use a command-line utility for the copy, then your `while...do` method is about the best you will get. The alternative is to write a script in some language (eg Python using boto3) that directly calls the S3-compatible `copy_object()` API. This will avoid the overhead of invoking the command-line utility for each object. Or, try to get `mc` working outside of a container?